# How to return error nil in go

Tags: go

I make a function that return error, even that function not error. How i make return nil if my function not error

```
func Serve() error {
   error = nil
   return error
}
```

something like that

Comment: You may want to spend one or two hours in the Tour of Go (http://tour.golang.org/) which ansers all such questions.

Answer (score 7):

`error` is type, so just

```
return nil
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func Serve() (err error) {
   err = nil
   return
}
```